# KeyedDecodingContainer always has zero keys

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

EDIT: **SOLUTION**

Thanks to @LeoDabus' answer below - to make my code work I changed my declaration of ImageKey as follows:

```
extension Image {
    enum ImageKey: String, CodingKey {
        case width = "Width"
        case height = "Height"
        case url = "Url"
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I am trying to implement a Decodable structure, Image. Image is very simple it looks like:

```
struct Image : Decodable {
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat
    let url: String
}
```

Of course, when I was trying to parse the json I received no member variables were being set. So I investigated further and I found that my decoder always had zero keys. Here are the keys I have been using:

```
enum ImageKey: String, CodingKey {
    case width = "width"
    case height = "height"
    case url = "url"
}
```

I have tried keys without the explicit instantiation, e.g.:

```
enum ImageKey: String, CodingKey {
    case width
    case height
    case url
}
```

same results.

Here is my init from decoder:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
{
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ImageKey.self)

    width = try container.decodeIfPresent(CGFloat.self, forKey: .width) ?? 0.0

    height = try container.decodeIfPresent(CGFloat.self, forKey: .height) ?? 0.0

    url = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .url) ?? ""
}
```

When I put a breakpoint in the init method and examine container it looks like:

[image: inspecting container]

It looks to me that container should have keys (width, height, url) but doesn't and that would be a plausible reason why the decoder never finds anything.

Here is the sample json I am testing against, I'm wondering if the capitalisation is helping / hindering:

```
{
    "Width": 800,
    "Height": 590,
    "Url": "https://obfuscated.image.url/image.jpg"
}
```

Has anyone seen this? Knows why container has zero keys?

Thanks for reading and as always any help always appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add a sample of the json itself which should be parsed? I just used a dummy json: `let json = """
{
"width": 11.123,
"height": 22.456,
"url": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739044/keyeddecodingcontainer-always-has-zero-keys"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!` and your code worked for me even for both enums...

Comment: Make sure you declare the coding keys enumeration as an instance of Image structure `extension Image { private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case width, height, url } }`

Comment: Aside bar note: if you are pretty sure that all properties (width, height, url) will be received from the json, there is no need to use `container.decodeIfPresent`, you just need to `container.decodeIf`. Otherwise you should declare your properties as optionals.

Comment: I just copy pasted your code in a playground and it's working fine for me. What is the issue you are facing ? Did you decoding a valid json with this ?

Comment: @LeoDabus I've just done what you said and it started working - If you want to create an answer I will mark it as correct. Many Thanks

Comment: I've declared the enum outside the struct and still it works for me. I'm not sure what is going on @LeoDabus